# List all tables, columns and types in Teradata SQL?

Tags: teradatasql

I would like to translate the following Oracle SQL query into Teradata SQL:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

This query retrieves all the tables, columns and their types. What is the Teradata SQL equivalent?

Comment: Closest analog would be `dbc.ColumnsV` dictionary view. Or for a single table or column you can use a HELP TABLE or HELP COLUMN statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and play a little:

```
SELECT  DatabaseName,
        TableName,
        CreateTimeStamp,
        LastAlterTimeStamp
FROM    DBC.TablesV
```